# Установка пакетов requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Чтобы сформировать список всех пакетов использую:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

При установке пакетов на новой машине:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Возник вопрос, если на "новой" машине отсутствует подключение к интернету (конечно же можно в ручную загрузить каждый пакет, после чего так же установить). Однако если в проекте используется ни один десяток пакетов, то это займет достаточно много времени. Есть ли способ к примеру загрузить все пакеты ссылаясь на requirements.txt в директорию, а после из директории их установить.

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать virtual environment, как это делают IDE и выгрузить:)

Вот тут расписано как это можно сделать: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-python-virtual-environments-on-ubuntu-18-04/

А можно просто взять уже сделанную из пайчарма, например